# Speed up mongodump+mongorestore

Tags: ssh, mongodb, ssh-tunnel, socket

I have created a script to copy a MongoDB database to my machine. I am creating an SSH tunnel (`ssh -L ...`) then I connect to the tunnelled port with `mongodump` then I pipe its output to `mongorestore`:

```
mongodump --host=127.0.0.1:##### --db=***** --archive | mongorestore --host={mongo_dest} --drop --archive
```

I would like to speed up the copying. `--gzip` doesn't make sense to be used in this case -- because the same machine and memory are used by `mongodump` and `mongorestore`. The data comes uncompressed via the SSH socket.

Is there a way to run `mongodump` on the SSHed machine and pipe its output to a process on my machine?

Of course I could dump the database, archive, copy over SSH and restore it. But I don't want taking temporary space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know why I didn't think of it:

```
ssh *** ". /etc/profile; mongodump --host=127.0.0.1:27017 --db=**** --archive --gzip" | mongorestore --host=127.0.0.1:27017 --drop --archive --gzip
```

Was `1603.96 real        45.24 user        43.57 sys`.

Now `209.52 real         7.25 user         6.03 sys`.

Comment: My loads sped up tenfold from this. Thank you.